# website page background in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

this is my code.my image dimensions are 1024X768 but i m getting a right-left scroll bar.and when i scroll to right ,i get a black background cutt off from my total image.
Help me out plzz

```css
body {
  background-image: url('stareffect1.jpg');
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 480px;
}
form #Edit1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 58px;
  left: 341px;
}
form #Edit2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 67px;
  left: 341px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img src="banner.jpg" width="500" height="70" />
  </head>

  </head>


  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <a href="forum.php">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:347px; top:165px;">
      <img src="images/forum.jpg" />
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="credits.php">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:481px; top:165px;">
      <img src="images/credits.jpg" />
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="rules.php">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:615px; top:165px;">
      <img src="images/rules.jpg" />
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="logout.php">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:740px; top:165px;">
      <img src="images/logout.jpg" />
    </div>
  </a>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div style="position:relative; left:339px; top:49px">
    <img src="images/actor.jpg" width="250" height="300" />
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:225px">
    <img src="images/river.jpg" width="250" height="300" />
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: plzz help me out.i am nt able to idenitfy the problem . is there any problem in placing pictures ?????????

Comment: Your html is completely corrupted. Don't use the head tag inside the body tag. Use it before the body tag. You have two closing </head> tags and no opening one. You should correct this major html issues and test again.

Comment: <html>

<head>
<img src="banner.jpg" width="500" height="70" />
</head>

<style type="text/css">
body {background-image:url('stareffect.jpg');}
</style>

Comment: i corrected it as in above given code bt it didn't help me.plzz suggest something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris is right your html is not well formatted. Try nesting the tags like below

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

body 
{
   background-image:url('redbg.png');
}

h1
{
   position: relative;
   left:  480px;       
}   

form #Edit1 
{ 
   position:relative; 
   top:58px; 
   left:   341px; 
}

form #Edit2 
{ 
   position:relative; 
   top:67px; 
   left:41px; 
}


</style>

</head>

<body>

<img src="banner.jpg" width="500" height="70" />

<style type="text/css">
body {background-image:url('stareffect1.jpg');}
</style>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
h1
 {
        position: relative;
        left:  480px;       
        }   
form #Edit1 { position: relative; 
               top:    58px; 
               left:   341px; 
              }
form #Edit2 { position: relative; 
               top:    67px; 
               left:   341px; 
              }

</style>

<hr/>
<br/>

<a href="forum.php"><div style="position:absolute; left:347px; top:165px;"><img src="images/forum.jpg"/></div></a>
<a href="credits.php"><div style="position:absolute; left:481px; top:165px;"><img src="images/credits.jpg"/></div></a>

<a href="rules.php"><div style="position:absolute; left:615px; top:165px;"><img src="images/rules.jpg"/></div></a>
<a href="logout.php"><div style="position:absolute; left:740px; top:165px;"><img src="images/logout.jpg"/></div></a>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="position:relative; left:339px; top:49px"></div>

<div style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:225px"> 
<img src="images/river.jpg" width="250" height="300" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

GB

Comment: <html>

<head>



<style type="text/css">

body 
   {
    background-image:url('stareffect.jpg');
    }





  h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left:  480px;  
     } 
form #Edit1 { position: relative; 
               top:    58px; 
               left:   341px; 
              }
form #Edit2 { position: relative; 
               top:    67px; 
               left:   341px; 
              }
      
</style>
</head>
<body>

Comment: @GB i edited my code according ur suggestiom .but still there is scroll bar .plzz suggest something